# How to get a return value from a send.Message and include the returned value as part of second message in MSMQ?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, windows-server-2008, msmq

I'm pretty new to MSMQ 4.0. I got stuck with below scenario;
Service A takes User Details and Returns an User ID.
Then Service B takes Billing detials with User ID.
Now I have to Queue these steps. I'm planning to use Transaction Queue.
Could some one please help me with
1)Get the ID from first message and include it in the second message.
2)If at least one step failed I have to rollback(transaction Queue does it for me) retry or 5 times and if it still failed then move it to VerifyAdminQueue for verification by Admin.I dont like using DeadLetter Queue etc.,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services built with MSMQ queues are truly one-way. This means that there is no built in concept of a response. There are many ways you can implement a request-response communication pattern using MSMQ but with all of them you will need to construct and send the response back to the caller yourself.

With one way actions, rollback is very simple, and indeed MSMQ will rollback any failed steps in the transmission of a message. More complex operations such as request-response however lack any concept of a transaction in MSMQ and so any rollback across more than one message transmission steps will require you to write compensatory code.